# Can we use different name for fields of two different REST end points representing same data

Tags: rest

Consider the scenario where I am building two end points to represent student information.

```
GET /api/schools/{id}/students/{id}
{
"studentName":"foo",
"teacherName":"bar"
.......
.....
}
```

and

```
GET /api/students/{id}
{
"studentName":"foo"
}
```

According to https://dzone.com/articles/naming-conventions-from-uncle-bobs-clean-code-phil(2.10 Add Meaningful context as a last resort), ideally I don't need to use `studentName` in `/api/students/{id}`. But if those two API's are being served by the same application, my defense is **Representing same data with different field names might create confusion**.

I searched across google but couldn't find the answer on which way should be considered.

EDIT:
What if there is another end point Teacher's favorite student /api/schools/{id}/teacher_fav_student/{id} and has the field studentName. Does this statement still hold valid?

Comment: Does the result of `/api/schools/{id}/students/{id}` and `/api/students/{id}` represent the same concept of a student? If yes, it should look the same, if no, the endpoint should have a different name.

Comment: What if there is another end point Teacher's favorite student `/api/schools/{id}/teacher_fav_student/{id}` and has the field `studentName`. Does this statement still hold valid? If so do you have any doc's/wiki's to support this. I prefer to use the same field name but my team thinks otherwise.

Comment: There are no absolute rules which hold in all situations. Therefore I wrote *should*, because it's a general rule of thumb. But of course there may be situtions, where you may need to find a different approach.